# MemoryError: mitmproxy has crashed

Tags: mitmproxy

**MemoryError: mitmproxy has crashed**

```
Jul 16 13:02:40 cubedev-PowerEdge-R330 bash[21256]: MemoryError
Jul 16 13:02:40 cubedev-PowerEdge-R330 bash[21256]: mitmproxy has crashed!
Jul 16 13:02:40 cubedev-PowerEdge-R330 bash[21256]: Please lodge a bug report at: https://github.com/mitmproxy/mitmproxy
Jul 16 13:02:40 cubedev-PowerEdge-R330 bash[21256]: 192.168.50.117:60549: Traceback (most recent call last):
Jul 16 13:02:40 cubedev-PowerEdge-R330 bash[21256]: File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mitmproxy/proxy/server.py", line 121, in handle
Jul 16 13:02:40 cubedev-PowerEdge-R330 bash[21256]: root_layer()
Jul 16 13:02:40 cubedev-PowerEdge-R330 bash[21256]: File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mitmproxy/proxy/modes/transparent_proxy.py", line 19, in call
Jul 16 13:02:40 cubedev-PowerEdge-R330 bash[21256]: layer()
Jul 16 13:02:40 cubedev-PowerEdge-R330 bash[21256]: File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mitmproxy/proxy/protocol/tls.py", line 285, in call
Jul 16 13:02:40 cubedev-PowerEdge-R330 bash[21256]: layer()
Jul 16 13:02:40 cubedev-PowerEdge-R330 bash[21256]: File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mitmproxy/proxy/protocol/http1.py", line 83, in call
Jul 16 13:02:40 cubedev-PowerEdge-R330 bash[21256]: layer()
Jul 16 13:02:40 cubedev-PowerEdge-R330 bash[21256]: File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mitmproxy/proxy/protocol/http.py", line 190, in call
Jul 16 13:02:40 cubedev-PowerEdge-R330 bash[21256]: if not self._process_flow(flow):
Jul 16 13:02:40 cubedev-PowerEdge-R330 bash[21256]: File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mitmproxy/proxy/protocol/http.py", line 397, in _process_flow
Jul 16 13:02:40 cubedev-PowerEdge-R330 bash[21256]: self.read_response_body(f.request, f.response)
Jul 16 13:02:40 cubedev-PowerEdge-R330 bash[21256]: MemoryError
Jul 16 13:02:40 cubedev-PowerEdge-R330 bash[21256]: Exception in response:[Errno 12] Cannot allocate memory
Jul 16 13:02:40 cubedev-PowerEdge-R330 bash[21256]: message repeated 37 times: [ Exception in response:[Errno 12] Cannot allocate memory]
```

**Steps to reproduce the behavior:**

Issue observed when 2 clients are connected to mitmdump.The crash is observed within 10 minutes

**System Information**

mitmdump --version
Mitmproxy: 5.1.1
Python: 3.6.0
OpenSSL: OpenSSL 1.1.1g 21 Apr 2020
Platform: Linux-4.15.0-45-generic-x86_64-with-debian-stretch-sid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

mitmproxy processes all request/responses in-memory, hence if you do a large download mitmproxy requires at least the same amount of RAM.

You can configure mitmproxy to "stream" (directly pass through) large requests and response bodies using the [option](https://docs.mitmproxy.org/stable/concepts-options/) `stream_large_bodies`:

```
mitmproxy --set stream_large_bodies=10m
```

This streams all bodies that are larger than 10MB (AFAIR a streamed body will not be processed by any filter and is also not captured).

Additionally you should save the collected requests/response using the `-w` option.

Comment: Thanks Robert for your answer. Let me try this first and i ll come up with the results.

Comment: This can be a workaround to MITM memory leak. At least the ram size won't grow faster. Thanks, Robert for the answer.