# Limit MITMproxy memory usage

Tags: mitmproxy, webproxy

We plan on using mitmproxy for our test and staging environments. However, we are running into the issue that these environments have limited memory available. MITMproxy seems (according to spec?) to simply store all our HTTPS API communications in memory. Since our applications use API's very intensively we fear we would run out of memory rather quickly.

So I was wondering, is there a good way to limit memory usage of MITMproxy?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MemoryError: mitmproxy has crashed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62932169/memoryerror-mitmproxy-has-crashed)

Comment: I am not sure if it is the mitmproxy GUI that keeps all data in RAM or that you don't save the data to disk. I use `mitmdump` and save everything to file using `-w <filename>` option and don't have any memory problems.

Comment: @Robert how would that work? You simply save everything to a file? Can you then still use some GUI / webinterface to view that? We simply want to have an extra window open where we can see what our project is currently doing regarding API calls. And we can't rely on having to manually SSH into our virtual machines to fetch any log files.

We currently use CamillaProxy for this purpose as it only logs locally when the window is open (so it's gone when window is closed), but is has sadly been abandoned.

Comment: Mitmproxy/mitmdump have an optional web interface [mitmweb](https://docs.mitmproxy.org/stable/tools-mitmweb/) that may be of use to you. But when what will be logged to RAM or disk I don't know. Just try it out yourself.